# how to parse this web service using retrofit in android?

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

http://www.superbinstruments.com/directory/index.php?r=webservice/profile/id/4096

Here i want to pass ID in the URL (like above) and JsonObject (can be null) in the Body.

Here the concept is like when i pass null to the json object it will retrieve the profile data or if i pass the json object with profile information then it will update the profile data.

I have tried below methods but i can retrieve the data but i can not update the data.
To update the data we we can pass same JSON response as Body.

```
@POST("index.php")
Call<UserProfile> profileUser(@Query("r") String value, @Body String user);

@POST("index.php?")
Call<UserProfile> saveUser(@Query("r") String value, @Body JSONObject user);
```

I am passing like:
value= webservice/profile/id/4096

if I pass as Json String as profile updated info then i am getting
"Invalid request password not needed."
OR 
 if I will pass as JsonObject as profile updated info 
then i am getting 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

The link you have posted not required any body to post. Remove `Body` from your code. To use `@Field` you have to annotate method as `@FormUrlEncoded`

Your method should be like this.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index.php?r=webservice/profile/id/")
Call<UserProfile> saveUser(@Field("value") String value);
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thank you sir, for answering, I need Body because the concept is like when i will not pass body then it retrieve whole data and when i pass body then it update the data

Comment: Then you shouldn't send json object. You should use model class object in your body. Retrofit will convert it into json

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer if it solves your issue. It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

```
@POST("index.php")
Call<User> getInstruments(@Query("r") String webservice, @Body User user);
```

And you should have to pass JSON using your model class as **Bhuvanesh** suggested

```
JSONObject jObj = null;
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject();
        jObj.put("firstname", "Kunjan Shah");
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

User user = new User();
user.setData(jObj);
```

And here is your model class

```
public class User {

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public JSONObject getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    String success;
    String message;
    JSONObject data;
}
```

And call your service by passing this two parameter

> Call update_user_profile =
>   yourapiinterfaceobject.getInstruments("webservice/profile/id/4096", user);

Comment: i can retrieve the data but can not update the profile data, both time repsonse like retrieve data succesfully. but when i pass the json it should be updated data successfully